# why is data from tf-agents buffer in random order

Tags: python, tensorflow, buffer, tf-agent

tl-dr version: why do the first 2 action/observations i take not line up with my first two objects in my replay buffer?

Do tf-agent replay buffers automatically shuffle data around?

by adding these prints im able to see what my first 2 steps look like

```
print("just addding this as traj num = "+str(num))
print(" next time step  = "+str(next_time_step))
replay_buffer.add_batch(traj)
```

this produces

```
just addding this as traj num = 0
 next time step  = TimeStep(
{'discount': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>,
 'observation': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1, 5, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]]]], dtype=float32)>,
 'reward': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([-0.05], dtype=float32)>,
 'step_type': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([2])>})
just addding this as traj num = 1
 next time step  = TimeStep(
{'discount': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>,
 'observation': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1, 5, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1., 1., 0.]]]], dtype=float32)>,
 'reward': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([-0.05], dtype=float32)>,
 'step_type': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([2])>})
```

a few lines later when i have my data set as an iterator, i once again explicitly print the first data points. (i have set my batch size to 3 so we should get the first 3 results, we seem to get 3 copies  of the first result)

```
Trajectory(
{'action': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[3],
       [0],
       [0]])>,
 'discount': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]], dtype=float32)>,
 'next_step_type': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[2],
       [2],
       [2]])>,
 'observation': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1, 1, 5, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]]],



       [[[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]]],



       [[[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]]]], dtype=float32)>,
 'policy_info': (),
 'reward': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-1.  ],
       [-0.05],
       [ 1.  ]], dtype=float32)>,
 'step_type': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0],
       [0],
       [0]])>})
### experience 1 above
### experience 1 above
### experience 1 above
```

the experiences are blank. if we continue to iterate through we continue to get the same results.

what is wrong with this? How can i keep the data in the replay buffer in the same order i collected it?

########################

reproducable example below (much of the game has been gutted to make it smaller)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tf_agents.networks import q_network
from tf_agents.agents.dqn import dqn_agent
import tf_agents
import tf_agents.environments.py_environment as PyEnvironment 
from tf_agents.trajectories import time_step as ts
import numpy as np
import keras 
import tf_agents.policies.random_tf_policy as random_tf_policy
import tf_agents.environments as tf_py_environment
import numpy as np
import random
import copy

class simple_slots():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x_rows = x
        self.y_rows = y
        self.slots = []
        for i in range(x):
            ys=[]
            for j in range(y):
                ys.append(0)
            self.slots.append(ys)
    def new_game(self):
        for xs in self.slots:
            for slot in xs:
                slot = 0
        
    def find_lowest_slot(self , x):
        lowest_y = 0
        best_slot = "none"
        for slot, y_ind in zip(reversed(self.slots[x]), reversed(range(len(self.slots[x])))):
            if slot == 0:
                if y_ind > lowest_y:
                    lowest_y = y_ind
                    best_slot = slot
        if best_slot != "none":
            return lowest_y
        return False
    
    def ml_plays_turn(self, action):
        y = self.find_lowest_slot(action)
        self.slots[action][y] = 1
    
    def script_plays_turn(self, action = 5):
        y = self.find_lowest_slot(action)
        self.slots[action][y] = 2
        
    def arbirtrarily_decide_if_game_over(self):
        if random.random() < 0.2:
            reward = 1
        elif  random.random() < 0.5:
            reward = -1
        else:
            reward = 0
        return reward

class Con4Env(PyEnvironment.PyEnvironment):
    
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        self._action_spec = tf_agents.specs.BoundedArraySpec(
            shape=(), dtype=np.int32, minimum=0, maximum=game.x_rows-1 , name='action')
        self._observation_spec = tf_agents.specs.BoundedArraySpec(
            shape=(1, game.x_rows,game.y_rows), dtype=np.float32, minimum=0, name='observation')
        self._state = np.zeros((game.x_rows,game.y_rows) , dtype=np.float32)
        self._time_step_spec = ts.time_step_spec(self._observation_spec)
        self._episode_ended = False
        
    def action_spec(self):
        return self._action_spec

    def observation_spec(self):
        return self._observation_spec

    def _reset(self):
        self._state = np.zeros((game.x_rows,game.y_rows) , dtype=np.float32)
        self._episode_ended = False
        return ts.restart(np.array([self._state], dtype=np.float32))
    
    def copy_gameboard_to_state(self):
        for ys, yind in zip(self.game.slots, range(len(self.game.slots))):
            for x , xind in zip(ys, range(len(ys))):
                self._state[xind][yind] = x

    def _step(self, action):
        if self._episode_ended:
            return self.reset()
                               
        reward = self.game.arbirtrarily_decide_if_game_over()
        if reward != 0:
            self._episode_ended = True
            
            
        elif self.game.ml_plays_turn(action):
            self.game.script_plays_turn()
            self.copy_gameboard_to_state()
        else:
            reward = -0.05 #### column full,     call it draw 
            self._episode_ended = True
                               
        if self._episode_ended: #### if game was ended last round the reward then we go in here 1 last time                             
            self.game.new_game()
            self.copy_gameboard_to_state()
            return ts.termination(np.array([self._state], dtype=np.float32), reward)
        else:
            self.copy_gameboard_to_state()
            return ts.transition(np.array([self._state], dtype=np.float32), reward=0.0, discount=0.0)
            
game = simple_slots(5,5)
the_env = Con4Env(game)
eval_env = Con4Env(game)
the_env = tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(the_env)
eval_env = tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(eval_env)

#    create time_step_spec
from tf_agents.utils import common
step_type_spec = tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.dtypes.int32, name='step_type') # just declare a time step spec 
reward_spec= tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, name='reward_spec')
discount_spec= tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, name='discount_spec')
time_step_spec = tf_agents.trajectories.TimeStep( step_type_spec ,reward_spec, discount_spec, the_env.observation_spec() )

#####################################################################

q_net = tf_agents.networks.q_network.QNetwork(
    input_tensor_spec = the_env.observation_spec(),
    action_spec = the_env.action_spec(),
    preprocessing_layers=None,
    preprocessing_combiner=None,
    conv_layer_params=None,
    fc_layer_params=(75, 40),
    dropout_layer_params=None,
    activation_fn=tf.keras.activations.relu,
    kernel_initializer=None,
    batch_squash=True,
    dtype=tf.float32,
    q_layer_activation_fn=None,
    name='QNetwork'
)

train_step_counter = tf.Variable(0)
gamma = 0.99
min_q_value = -20 
max_q_value = 20  
n_step_update = 2 
agent = dqn_agent.DqnAgent( 
    time_step_spec , 
    the_env.action_spec() , 
    q_net, 
    optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.000001),
    n_step_update=n_step_update,
    td_errors_loss_fn=common.element_wise_squared_loss,
    gamma=gamma,
    train_step_counter=train_step_counter
)

random_policy = random_tf_policy.RandomTFPolicy(time_step_spec, the_env.action_spec())


# data collector 

data_spec=agent.collect_data_spec
print(data_spec)
from tf_agents.utils import common
import copy
replay_buffer_capacity = 999
initial_collect_steps = 50
batch_size = 3
n_step_update = 1
num_parallel_calls = 2
replay_buffer = tf_agents.replay_buffers.TFUniformReplayBuffer(
    data_spec=agent.collect_data_spec,
    batch_size=the_env.batch_size,
    max_length=replay_buffer_capacity
)

def collect_step(environment, policy, num):
    if environment.current_time_step().is_last():
        time_step = environment.reset()
    else:
        time_step = environment.current_time_step()
    action_step = policy.action(time_step)
    next_time_step = environment.step(action_step.action)
    traj = tf_agents.trajectories.from_transition(time_step, action_step, next_time_step)
    print("just addding this as traj num = "+str(num))
    print(" next time step  = "+str(next_time_step))
    replay_buffer.add_batch(traj)

nom = 0 
for _ in range(initial_collect_steps):
    collect_step(the_env, random_policy , nom)
    nom+=1

#    after each step check to see if data is in order 

dataset = replay_buffer.as_dataset(
num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls, 
sample_batch_size=batch_size,
num_steps=n_step_update).prefetch(9)

iterator = iter(dataset)
experience, unused_info = next(iterator)
print(experience)#### why is this thing out of order
for i in range(3):
    print("### experience 1 above")
experience, unused_info = next(iterator)
print(experience)#### why is this thing out of order
for i in range(3):
    print("### experience 2 above")
```

Answer (score 0):

Late response for those still looking.

```
    replay_buffer = tf_uniform_replay_buffer.TFUniformReplayBuffer(
    data_spec,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    max_length=max_length)

    dataset = replay_buffer.as_dataset(sample_batch_size=32, num_steps=2, num_parallel_calls=1, single_deterministic_pass=True)

    iterator = iter(dataset)
    sample = next(iterator)
```

Notes about the code:

1. num_steps in the `.as_dataset()` call tells how man sequential rows to pull. This is helpful in models that rely on both the current step and next step. (Not applicable in your case since `n_step_update=1`,), but mentioned for generality. The behavior isn't necessarily intuitive.

Consider a batch size 32.

replay_buffer.add_batch(my_batch_32)
replay_buffer.add_batch(my_new_batch_32)

num_steps would pull the first element from the first batch and the second elmement from the second batch.

Here are my notes detailing this process and how to use it.

```
def get_buffer():
    data_spec =  (
        tf.TensorSpec([3], tf.float32, 'action')
    )

    batch_size = 32
    max_length = 1000

    replay_buffer = tf_uniform_replay_buffer.TFUniformReplayBuffer(
        data_spec,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        max_length=max_length)


    for i in tf.range(1,2, dtype=np.float32):
        action = tf.cast(i,dtype=np.float32) * np.ones(
            data_spec.shape.as_list(), dtype=np.float32)

        values = (action)
        values_batched = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda t: tf.stack([t] * batch_size),
                                           values)
        print(values_batched)
        replay_buffer.add_batch(values_batched)

    return replay_buffer

replay_buffer = get_buffer()
dataset = replay_buffer.as_dataset(sample_batch_size=32, num_steps=2, num_parallel_calls=1, single_deterministic_pass=True)

sampler = iter(dataset)

# note because dataset num_steps=2, this will generate a sample of size (sample_batch_size, num_steps, size_action_space)
# this means if batch 1 is all tf.ones() and batch 2 is 2* tf.ones(), the first element with be (1,2), NOT (1,1). ie you will get 32 (1,2) records
sample, _ = next(sampler)

    """--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations of Replay Buffer use:
- Replay buffer batch size tells how many items should be added at a single time to the buffer
    -If you don't add that many during an add_batch() call, it fails
- Dataset single_Deterministic_pass can be used to get a random sample if False, or a deterministic sample if True
- as_dataset()
    - Batch size tells how many to records to pull. It does not have to be the same as replay_buffer batch size
    - num_steps tells how many consecutive rows to combine into a single "row". Some loss functions (SAC) require two
      which pertain to the current and next time steps
- next(iter(dataset)) gets the first value from a batch, then the next from the following batch when considering num_steps.
    -This implies that a batch should be thought of as the SAME time step?
    - when sampling with deterministic=False, it can sample the same element multiple times.
- next() throws an OutOfRangeError()
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"""
```